# Getting undefined on retrieving value

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have text field called "Proveedor" like this:

```
<tr>
        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><span class="ms-h3 ms-standardheader" id="Proveedor">
        <nobr>Proveedor</nobr>
    </span></td>
        <td valign="top" width="350px" class="ms-formbody">
        <!-- FieldName="Proveedor"
             FieldInternalName="Proveedor"
             FieldType="SPFieldText"
          -->
            <span dir="none"><input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" id="Proveedor_9ae60a83-59a5-4415-84d8-51ba698b8538_$TextField" title="Proveedor" style="ime-mode : " class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true"><br></span>



        </td>
    </tr>
```

That I want to do is to get value of that field, so I try:

```
var emailSpan = $("input[id='Proveedor']").val()
```

But I got undefined, someone knows what am I doing wrong? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID that you have used i.e `Proveedor` is the ID of `td` and not the `input` tag.
That's why you are getting undefined. ID of your `input` tag is different.

Try below code:

```
var emailSpan = $("input[title='Proveedor']").val()
```

OR

```
var emailSpan = $("input[id='Proveedor_9ae60a83-59a5-4415-84d8-51ba698b8538_$TextField']").val()
```